# django serializer dropping field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a django app and I'm serializing my views, but when applying the serializer to the model is dropping the fields I wanna serialize:

models.py

```
class vehicles_model(models.Model):
    pk_idmodel = models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdModel', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)
    fk_idbrand= models.ForeignKey(vehicles_brand, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdVehicleBrand', related_name='Brand')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_model'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Models"
```

serializers.py

```
class brandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_brand
        fields = ['name']   
        depth = 3

class modelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    Brand = brandSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_model
        fields = ['name', 'Brand']   
        depth = 3
```

output:

```
    {
        "name": "Aveo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Spark"
    },
```

Which is the model name, but the brand is dropped, I've been unable to fix it after checking other solutiones, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: Your field name `Branch` in serializer is not same with source field in model class i.e. `fk_idbrand`.
Change to: `brandSerializer(source="fk_idbrand", many=True, read_only=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `brandSerializer` serializer to include the `brand` field

```
class brandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_brand
        fields = ['name', 'brand`]   
        depth = 3
```